# Problems installing Laravel Homestead on MAC

Tags: laravel, ssh, vagrant, virtual-machine, homestead

I'm trying to install **laravel homestead** (with php 7) on my local machine (Mac OS X El Capitan). I've already installed vagrant and Virtualbox.

When I follow the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead#introduction) I start with the command `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`. This doesn't cause any problems:

[image]

The following step is:

```
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
```

That also works. The next step is:

```
bash init.sh
```

This command should create a **Homestead.yml** in a hidden directory `~/.homestead`. This doesn't happen! He creates the **Homestead.yml** in the `~/Homestead` directory.... .

Then I've edited the *Homestead.yml* in my **~/Homestead** folder to:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/projects
      to: /home/vagrant/projects

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Then I've tried to run `vagrant up` in **~/Homestead folder**. But I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Can someone help me with the installation of Homestead?

Comment: Your vagrant and virtual box are latest one? Whats the version of your vagrant ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating your vagrant and virtual box to latest version will solve the problem.

Comment: I was caught by this same problem. It's annoying, because the auto-update feature in VirtualBox 5 does not detect that version 6 is available, so it tells you that you're up-to-date, when you are not.